# Not automount with encfs on login?

Tags: linux, encfs

I would like to use encfs to create an encrypted folder but i do not want to automatically mount it when the user logs in. I'd like to type the password eachtime. How do i configure it to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use encfs normally.

```
encfs ~/.private ~/private
```

You only need special setup if you want *automatic* unlocking.

(By the way, kernel-mode eCryptFS usually offers better performance.)

Comment: i could swear it automatically mounts on logins.... maybe i was using su from root. But i could swear su from root made it not to do that. I'll accept when i can double check this

Comment: Check your PAM config - it could be that your distro automatically installs pam_encfs - but even then, it wouldn't automagically know the mount location.n't automagically know the mount location.